# Jquery/ javascript functions messing up my form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

This question might sound crazy, but everytime I put javascript or jquery <del>codes</del> on my form,

when I input date on my HTML 5 textbox disappears, but when I refresh the page the text comes back.

I don't know what's going on with my code

here is my markup:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="myClaimForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="myAsiaIns.myClaimForm" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title>File A claim </title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/_clientLandingPage.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/_claimFormContents.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/_responsiveClaimForm.css" />



       <style type="text/css">
        #title {
            width: 970px;
        }
        #homecontents {
            width: 1187px;
            height: 863px;
        }
        #registration {
            height: 238px;
        }
        A{text-decoration:none;
            color: #27AE60;
            font-size: small;
        }

        .myLink
        {
        color:#888888;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: medium;
        }
        .myLink:hover
        {
        color: white;
        text-decoration:underline;
        }
        .myTextbox 
        {

        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        }
           .auto-style1 {
               color: #F39C12;
           }
           #claimformisprintable {
               height: 1181px;
           }
           #natureofloss {
               height: 68px;
           }
           #decorator1 {
               width: 619px;
               height: 72px;
           }
           #decoratorcontents {
               height: 46px;
           }
            input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
         display: none;
         }
           </style>
           <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ddlDrivers').change(function () {
                $.blockUI({
                    message: '<h1>Please Wait.</h1>',
                    css: {
                        border: '1px solid black',
                        padding: '15px',
                        backgroundColor: 'white',
                        '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                        '-moz-border-radius': '10px',

                        color: 'Black',
                        size: '10px'
                    }

                });

                setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);
            });
        });

     </script>
     </head>
     <body id="myClaim">

     <form id="claimformmain" runat="server">
     <div id="logo">
        <div id="logoleft">
         <div id="holder">
             <div id="companyname">

                 <br />
                 <br />

                 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Logo.png" draggable="false" Height="98px" Width="239px" />

             </div>
             <div id="spacer"></div>
             <div id="homelink">
                 <br />
                 &nbsp;
                 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" style="font-size: medium; " CssClass="myLink" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Home</asp:HyperLink>
             </div>
             <div id="clientslink">
                 <br />
                 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" style="font-size: medium; " CssClass="myLink" NavigateUrl="~/clientLandingPage.aspx">Clients</asp:HyperLink>
             </div>
             <div id="extranetlink">
                 <br />
                 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" style="font-size: medium; " CssClass="myLink" NavigateUrl="~/extranet-Home.aspx">Extranet</asp:HyperLink>
             </div>
             <div id="aboutlink">
                 <br />
                 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" style="font-size: medium; " CssClass="myLink" NavigateUrl="~/aboutWebsite.aspx">About</asp:HyperLink>
             </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div id="logoright">
            <div id="holder2">
                <div id="welcomeuser">   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <br />
                </div>
                <div id="links">
                 &nbsp;
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblClaimFormUSER" runat="server" Text="xxxx" style="font-size: small"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;|
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUniqueID" runat="server" style="font-size: small" Text="XXXX"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Back </asp:LinkButton>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="claimform_main">
            <div id="decorator1">
                <br />
                <div id="decoratorcontents">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/ClaimFormImages/step1.png" draggable="false"/>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label30" runat="server" style="font-size: small" Text="Fill Out Claim Form"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="claimformcontents">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="font-size: x-large" Text="My Claim Form"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="We already generated your policy details. Please provide other necessary information. "></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div id="header1">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" style="color: #3498DB; font-size: large" Text="General Information"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div id="claimformisprintable">
                    <div id="claimleft1">
                        <div id="innerleft1">
                            <div id="align1">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="Issuance Office:"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="innerright1">
                            <div id="align2">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblIssuanceOffice" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="[issuanceoffice]" CssClass="auto-style1"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimright1">
                        <div id="innerleft2">
                            <div id="align3">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="Policy Number:"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="innerright2">
                            <div id="align4">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPolicyNumber" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style1" style="font-size: medium" Text="[Policy Number]"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="natureofloss">
                        <div id="claimleft2">
                            <div id="innerleft3"><div id="align5">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="Nature of Loss:"></asp:Label>
                                </div></div>
                             <div id="innerright3"><div id="align6">
                                 <asp:DropDownList ID="drpNatureofLoss" runat="server" Width="230px">
                                 </asp:DropDownList>
                                 </div></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="claimright2">


                    </div>
                        </div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="header2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" style="color: #3498DB; font-size: large" Text="Driver's Information"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="adddriversinstruct">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" style="font-size: small" Text="Choose from drivers that you added. Choose others option to specify the driver during the accident."></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" style="font-size: small" Text="All fields are mandatory."></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimleft3">
                        <div id="innerleft4"><div id="align7">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="Driver's Name:"></asp:Label>
                                </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright4"><div id="align8">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDrivers" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="230px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDrivers_SelectedIndexChanged" onblur="return CheckBlank(this)">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimright3">
                        <div id="innerleft5"><div id="align9">
                            <asp:TextBox  type="text" ID="txtDriverInput" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Height="16px" Visible="False" Width="234px" placeholder="Input Driver's Name Here" required="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright5"><div id="align10"></div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimleft4">
                        <div id="innerleft6"><div id="align11">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="License Type:"></asp:Label>
                                </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright6"><div id="align12">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="drpLicenseType" runat="server" Width="230px" Enabled="False">
                                <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimright4">
                        <div id="innerleft7"><div id="align13">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="License Number:"></asp:Label>
                                </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright7"><div id="align14">
                            <asp:TextBox class="validate[required]" type="text" ID="txtLicNum" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Width="230px" placeholder="N01-21-031576" Enabled="False" required="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimleft5">
                        <div id="innerleft8"><div id="align15">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="License Restriction:"></asp:Label>
                                </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright8"><div id="align16">
                            <asp:TextBox  type="text" ID="txtLicRic" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Width="230px" placeholder="123" Enabled="False" required="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimright5">
                        <div id="innerleft9"><div id="align17">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="License Expiry:"></asp:Label>
                                </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright9"><div id="align18">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLicExp" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Width="230px" Enabled="False" type="Date"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimleft6">
                        <div id="innerleft10"><div id="align19">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="License Address:"></asp:Label>
                                </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright10"><div id="align20">
                            <asp:TextBox type="text" ID="txtLicAdd" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Width="230px" placeholder="123 Manila City" Enabled="False" required="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimright6"></div>
                    <br />

                    <div id="header3">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" style="color: #3498DB; font-size: large" Text="Accident Information"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimleft7">
                        <div id="innerleft11"><div id="align21">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="Date of Accident:"></asp:Label>
                                </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright11"><div id="align22">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateofAccident" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Width="230px" placeholder="123 Manila City" type="Date"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimright7"><div id="innerleft12"><div id="align23">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="Time of Accident:"></asp:Label>
                                </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright12"><div id="align24">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTimeOfAccident" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Width="230px" placeholder="123 Manila City" type="Time"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimleft8"><div id="innerleft13"><div id="align25">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="Accident Information:"></asp:Label>
                                </div></div><div id="innerright13"><div id="align26">
                            <asp:TextBox  ID="txtAcciInfo" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Width="230px" type="Text" Height="101px" TextMode="MultiLine" placeholder="write something.." required="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div></div></div>
                    <div id="claimright8"></div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="header4">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" style="color: #3498DB; font-size: large" Text="Policy Summary"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimleft9">
                        <div id="innerleft14"><div id="align27">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label21" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="Policy Holder:"></asp:Label>
                                </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright14"><div id="align28">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPolicyHolder" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="[policyholder]" CssClass="auto-style1"></asp:Label>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimright9">
                        <div id="innerleft15"><div id="align29">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label22" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="Company:"></asp:Label>
                                </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright15"><div id="align30">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCompany" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="[company]" CssClass="auto-style1"></asp:Label>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimleft10">
                        <div id="innerleft16"><div id="align31">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label23" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="Address:"></asp:Label>
                                </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright16"><div id="align32">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="[address]" CssClass="auto-style1"></asp:Label>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimright10">
                        <div id="innerleft17"><div id="align33"></div></div>
                        <div id="innerright17"><div id="align34"></div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimleft11"><div id="innerleft18">
                                          <div id="align35">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label24" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="E-Mail Address:"></asp:Label>
                                          </div>
                                          </div>
                        <div id="innerright18"><div id="align36">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="[Eaddress]" CssClass="auto-style1"></asp:Label>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimright11"></div>
                    <div id="claimleft12">
                        <div id="innerleft19"><div id="align37">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label25" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="Insured Vehicle:"></asp:Label>
                                          </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright19"><div id="align38">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblVehi" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="[veh]" CssClass="auto-style1"></asp:Label>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimright12">
                        <div id="innerleft20"><div id="align39">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label26" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="Registered To:"></asp:Label>
                                          </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright20"><div id="align40">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblRegTo" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="[reg]" CssClass="auto-style1"></asp:Label>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimleft13"><div id="innerleft21"><div id="align41">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label27" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="Plate Number:"></asp:Label>
                                          </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright21"><div id="align42">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPlateNu" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="[plate]" CssClass="auto-style1"></asp:Label>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimright13"></div>
                    <div id="claimleft14">
                        <div id="innerleft22"><div id="align43">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label28" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="Engine Number:"></asp:Label>
                                          </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright22"><div id="align44">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblEngNu" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="[Eng]" CssClass="auto-style1"></asp:Label>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="claimright14">
                        <div id="innerleft23"><div id="align45">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="Serial Number:"></asp:Label>
                                          </div></div>
                        <div id="innerright23"><div id="align46">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSerNu" runat="server" style="font-size: medium" Text="[ser]" CssClass="auto-style1"></asp:Label>
                            </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="buttons">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" BackColor="#3498DB" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="White" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit Claim" />
                    &nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create a fiddle please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EuJLa/

Comment: How are you inputting the date?

Comment: I set type="date" to my textbox, my problem is, everything is working fine, but when I include any jquery or javascript to my form, it become somehow corrupted texts in drop down list is not showing properly, texts not showing..